# Poisson's equation for time dependent charge

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

Is Poisson's equation valid for a time dependent charge density? I think Poisson's equation is valid just for electrostatic fields. But I saw a [paper](http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.88.045405) that's used this equation for time dependent charge density. May anyone help me with this contradiction?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_potential

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Poisson's equation *can be* valid for time-varying fields. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson's_equation#Electrostatics) on the subject says in deriving
$$
\nabla^2\varphi=\frac{\rho_f}{\epsilon_0}\tag{1}
$$
that (my emphasis),

> The above discussion assumes that the magnetic field is not varying in time. The same Poisson equation arises even if it does vary in time, **as long as the Coulomb gauge is used**. In this more general context, computing $\varphi$ is no longer sufficient to calculate $\mathbf E$, since $\mathbf E$ also depends on the magnetic vector potential $\mathbf A$, which must be independently computed. See Maxwell's equation in potential formulation for more on $\varphi$ and $\mathbf A$ in Maxwell's equations and how Poisson's equation is obtained in this case.

Where the [Coulomb gauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#Coulomb_gauge) requires
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf A(\mathbf r,t)=0
$$
If we pick this gauge ([always possible](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/are-gauge-choices-in-electrodynamics-really-always-possible)), then the (1) is valid for electrodynamics.