# How do gauge transformation imply gauge conditions?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

In classical EM I understand the electric and magnetic fields are invariant under the potential transformations $\varphi\to\varphi - \partial_t\chi$ and $\mathbf{A}\to\mathbf{A} + \nabla\chi$.

From here people often say this gives us a freedom to do something like choose $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A} = 0$. I don't understand how we go from the above transformations to specifying properties that $\varphi$ and $\mathbf{A}$ satisfy.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1250/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\boldsymbol A$ does not satisfy $\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol A=0$, then redefine
$$
\tilde{\boldsymbol A}\equiv\boldsymbol A+\nabla\chi
$$
where $\chi$ is *any* solution of the PDE
$$
-\nabla^2\chi=\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol A
$$

The vector $\tilde{\boldsymbol A}$ satisfies, by construction, $\nabla\cdot \tilde{\boldsymbol A}=0$.

Comment: How do we know there are solutions to that PDE?

Comment: @NateStemen see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem_for_Poisson's_equation and http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node31.html (last equation).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, I think that your references discuss the uniqueness of the solution and not its existence.

Comment: @0x90 the first one discusses uniqueness. The second one gives the explicit solution (for a certain boundary conditions).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform who said the the integral converges? It depends on the boundary conditions too.

Comment: @0x90 the fact that $\boldsymbol A$ is a well-defined vector potential (with trivial topology) means that it has to be fast decaying at infinity. The boundary conditions are important for uniqueness, but here we only need *some* solution of the PDE. Any solution works.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform you are right I was talking in general. Thanks

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform what do you mean by a function having a trivial topology?

Comment: @NateStemen in some advanced gauge theories the behaviour of the gauge fields at infinity is important. It's not relevant for your question, so nevermind.