# Coulomb gauge choice: Does $A_0=0$ imply that we also need to choose $\nabla \cdot \vec{A} =0$ from the EOM of $A_0$?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, maxwell-equations, gauge

How to justify the Coulomb gauge fixing condition choice with
$$
A_0=0, \quad \nabla \cdot \vec{A} =0?
$$

Below in the text image, I find a text explaining that imposing $A_0=0$ is always possible because I think we set
$$
A_\mu \mapsto A_\mu' = A_\mu + \partial_\mu \omega.
$$

We can choose $A_0 \mapsto A_0' =  A_0 + \partial_0 \omega =0$.
This means finding $\omega$ such that $A_0 + \partial_0 \omega =0$.

Then we impose the equation of motion of $A_0$, which seems to be, at least for pure Maxwell theory, to
$$
\partial_j(\partial_j A^0 - \partial_0 A^j )=0.
$$

Even if $A^0 =0$, we have still
$$
\partial_j(   \partial_0 A^j )=0. \tag{1}
$$

This seems not implying that the Coulomb gauge condition requires
$$
\partial_j     A^j  =\nabla \cdot \vec{A} =0.  \tag{2}
$$

How to show that (1) can deduce (2)?

p.s. See also a different condition is discussed in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/33140/310987

[image]

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/544133/

Comment: I don't quite understand the question: 1. No one is saying that the equation of motion implies the gauge choice (i.e. $(1)\implies (2)$). If it did, it would not be a *choice*, would it? Why do you think you can deduce the gauge choice from an equation of motion? Why do we need to "justify" a gauge choice? 2. The answer you link discusses the exact same equation of motion, because $E^i = F^{i0} = \partial_i A^0 - \partial_0 A^i$. 3. Where is the screenshot at the end from? Please always cite your sources and type *out* text you want to quote so that it can be indexed by search engines.

Comment: It is from a lecture note - for example p.2 of http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory/72d.pdf